# Is there a way I can overwrite the colour the Material UI Icons npm package provides in React?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am new to React and am using the npm package Material UI icons (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons) and displaying icons within a React component as such:

Importing:

```
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/hardware/keyboard-arrow-right';
```

and rendering:

```
readMoreLink={<a href={someUrl} >Read more <KeyboardArrowRightIcon /></a>}
```

However, since `KeyboardArrowRightIcon` is an SVG provided by the npm package, it comes with it's own fill colour:

Eg: `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="display: inline-block; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);...`

I know I can override this colour by having a style attribute within the element, eg:

```
<KeyboardArrowRightIcon style={{ fill: '#0072ea' }} />
```

But is there anyway to make this a SCSS variable (`style={{ fill: $link-color }}`)?

I worry if the link colour changes in the style sheet someone will have to hunt down all these hard coded instances later.

Answer (score 105):

## Change Icon Color

```
<HomeIcon />
<HomeIcon color="primary" />
<HomeIcon color="secondary" />
<HomeIcon color="action" />
<HomeIcon color="disabled" />
<HomeIcon style={{ color: green[500] }} />
<HomeIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
```

## Change Icon Size

```
<HomeIcon fontSize="small" />
<HomeIcon />
<HomeIcon fontSize="large" />
<HomeIcon style={{ fontSize: 40 }} />
```

## MDI using Icon component

```
<Icon>add_circle</Icon>
<Icon color="primary">add_circle</Icon>
<Icon color="secondary">add_circle</Icon>
<Icon style={{ color: green[500] }}>add_circle</Icon>
<Icon fontSize="small">add_circle</Icon>
<Icon style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>add_circle</Icon>
```

## For the Font

```
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" />
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" color="primary" />
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" color="secondary" />
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" style={{ color: green[500] }} />
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" fontSize="small" />
<Icon className="fa fa-plus-circle" style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
```

[Resouces to learn more abo it](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/), [Icons](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/)

Answer (score 61):

Just add a style `fill: "green"`

Example: `<Star style={{fill: "green"}}/>`

Comment: In the old days of plain CSS, inline styles were frowned upon. I still believe that hammering style down to a single component is a [bad practice](http://jamesknelson.com/why-you-shouldnt-style-with-javascript/)

Comment: I am agreeing the inline style is bad. But still this answer doesn't even answer the original question. Let's say in future KeyboardArrowRightIcon changed the fill color to "red" then how will your hardcoded "green" value reflect the new "red" color?

Comment: how do you specify a css class though instead of hard coded green?  lets say I created a .font-green for example

Answer (score 32):

Update: 2022 July MUI5

There are multiple ways to change icon color

```
  <HomeIcon sx={{color: "#FC0"}} />
  <HomeIcon htmlColor="red" />
  <HomeIcon color="primary" />
  <HomeIcon color="success" />
  <HomeIcon color="action" />
  <HomeIcon color="disabled" />
  <HomeIcon color="error" />
  <HomeIcon sx={{ color: pink[500] }} />
```

[image: Icon colors]

Using `sx` prop you can specify any hex/rgb color code or colors from your [theme palette](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/color/#color-palette)

Example :

```
 import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';

 <HomeIcon sx={{ color: red[800] }} />
```

[image: red 800]

---

This is what I do

[image: how it looks]

I use MUI v4.5.1. Use the `color` prop [API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/icon/) with value inherit and add a div or span wrapper around and add your color there.

From the API docs

> `color` default value:`inherit`. The color of the component. It supports those theme colors that make sense for this component.

Add star icon

```
import React from 'react';
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/StarRounded';
import './styles.css';

export function FavStar() {
  return (
    <div className="star-container">
      <Star size="2em" fontSize="inherit" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In style.css

```
.star-container {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way to specify/override the color of an Icon in Material-UI is to use a custom [CSS class name](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-class-names).

Suppose that you want to show a green checkbox rather than a red triangle, depending on the outcome of some process.

You create a function somewhere inside your code, for example like this:

```
function iconStyles() {
  return {
    successIcon: {
      color: 'green',
    },
    errorIcon: {
      color: 'red',
    },
  }
}
```

You then apply [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) to that function, and run the result.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
...

const classes = makeStyles(iconStyles)();
```

Inside your render function, you can now use the object `classes`:

```
  const chosenIcon = outcome
    ? <CheckCircleIcon className={classes.successIcon} />
    : <ReportProblemIcon className={classes.errorIcon} />;
```

The function I mentioned first in this answer actually accepts a theme as input and allows you to modify/enrich that theme: this ensures that your custom classes aren't seen as exceptions, but rather as integrations inside a more comprehensive visual solution (for example, icon colors in a theme are best seen as [encodings](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/#css)).

Material-UI is very rich and I'd encourage you to explore also other existing [customisation mechanisms](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#customizing-components).

Answer (score 9):

You can do like this: `<PlusOne htmlColor="#ffaaee" />`

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I found is using the following.

```
import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Visibility } from '@material-ui/icons';

const MyVisibility = styled(Visibility)({
    color: 'white',
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set a default color for all icons by creating a [custom theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) with `createMuiTheme()`:

```
createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiSvgIcon: {
      htmlColor: '#aa0011',
    }
  }
})
```

This will set the default value of the `htmlColor` prop for every icon like `<KeyboardArrowRightIcon/>`. Here's a [list of other props](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/) you can set.

Comment: How is the parameter for the icons in the createTheme() function?

Answer (score 5):

## Overwriting the material UI Icon color like below

## [image]

in js

```
        const [activeStar, setActiveStar] = useState(false);

        <IconButton onClick={() => setActiveStar(!activeStar)}>
          {activeStar ? (
            <StarOutlined className="starBorderOutlined" />
          ) : (
            <StarBorderOutlined />
          )}
        </IconButton>
```

in Css

```
      .starBorderOutlined {
        color: #f4b400 !important;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Surprised that no one has suggested a site-wide solution yet.

You can override the colors that are assigned for the "colors" option here https://material-ui.com/api/icon/#props

by adding an override to your theme (you'll have to define a custom theme if you aren't already) https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#createmuitheme-options-args-theme

After defining a theme though, it's as simple as

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  "overrides": {
    MuiSvgIcon: {
      colorPrimary: {
        color: ["#625b5b", "!important"],
      },
      colorSecondary: {
        color: ["#d5d7d8", "!important"],
      },
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: The only thing with this approach is that you must declare the color property as "primary" for this to work rather than overriding the default color. You can override the root color with this approach but parents wont affect the children at this point. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 4):

To change color of your MUI Icons your have three ways: ([Source](https://www.brainstormcreative.co.uk/react-js/react-material-ui-icons/))

```
//using a hex value
<BathroomIconOutlined style={{ color: "#ffee66" }} />

//using a standard css colour
<BathroomTwoToneIcon style={{ color: "blue" }} />

//import a material ui colour, and use that
import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";
<BathroomIcon style={{ color: purple[500] }} />
```

Or use directly the MUI properties: ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVonkBWYeDU&ab_channel=TheNetNinja))

```
import SearchOutlined from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';

<SearchOutlined style={{ color: 'primary', fontSize: "small" }} />
<SearchOutlined style={{ color: 'secondary', fontSize: "medium" }} />
<SearchOutlined style={{ color: 'action', fontSize: "large" }} />
<SearchOutlined style={{ color: 'error', fontSize: 16 }} />
<SearchOutlined style={{ color: 'disabled', fontSize: 16 }} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Only correct solution that covers two tone (TwoTone) icons is to pass it **htmColor** property:

```
React.createElement(Icon, {htmlColor: "#00688b"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SvgIcon`](https://material-ui.com/api/svg-icon/), from the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-icons):

> The `SvgIcon` component takes an SVG `path` element as its child and
>   converts it to a React component that displays the path, and allows
>   the icon to be styled and respond to mouse events. SVG elements should
>   be scaled for a 24x24px viewport.

You must use the *devTools* to extract the path of the `KeyboardArrowRightIcon` icon:

[image: svg path]

Then use it with your custom color like this:

```
<SvgIcon
  component={svgProps => {
    return (
      <svg {...svgProps}>
        {React.cloneElement(svgProps.children[0], {
          fill: myColorVariable
        })}
      </svg>
    );
  }}
>
   <path d="M8.59 16.59L13.17 12 8.59 7.41 10 6l6 6-6 6-1.41-1.41z"></path>
</SvgIcon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, me solution was:

```
import React from 'react';
import pure from 'recompose/pure';
import {SvgIcon} from '@material-ui/core';

let smile = (props) => (
 <SvgIcon {...props}
  component={props => {
    return (
      <svg {...props}>
        {React.cloneElement(props.children[0], {
          fill: "#4caf50"
        })}
      </svg>
    );
  }}
>
   <path d="M256,32C132.281,32,32,132.281,32,256s100.281,224,224,224s224-100.281,224-224S379.719,32,256,32z M256,448
            c-105.875,0-192-86.125-192-192S150.125,64,256,64s192,86.125,192,192S361.875,448,256,448z M160,192c0-26.5,14.313-48,32-48
            s32,21.5,32,48c0,26.531-14.313,48-32,48S160,218.531,160,192z M288,192c0-26.5,14.313-48,32-48s32,21.5,32,48
            c0,26.531-14.313,48-32,48S288,218.531,288,192z M384,288c-16.594,56.875-68.75,96-128,96c-59.266,0-111.406-39.125-128-96"></path>
</SvgIcon>
);
smile = pure(smile);
smile.displayName = 'smile';
smile.muiName = 'SvgIcon';

export default smile;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Solution that works the best for myself:

const EditableIcon = ({ icon, color, sx }: PropsWithChildren<EditableIconProps>) => {
  const c = useIconStyles()
  return React.cloneElement(icon, {
    ...(color && { color }),
    ...(sx && { sx }),
    classes: {
      colorPrimary: c.colorPrimary,
      colorSecondary: c.colorSecondary,
      colorAction: c.colorAction
    }
  })
}
```

If color is set, your classes would override default values.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline styling
Instead of

> style={{ color: "green" }}

do

> sx={{ color: "green"}}