# How to change the Material Design icon's color from css?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have following icon:

```
<Icon
 path={mdiViewDashboardVariant}
 size={1}
 color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.548)"
 className={styles.linkIcon}
/>
```

I try to change its color using css but it's not working.

```
.linkIcon {
    color: white !important;
}
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: does this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68108403/13405106) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help as I need to change the color from the .css file.